# why @Qualifier not allowed above constructor?

Tags: java, spring

I am learning spring but while i tried below it doesn't work but at the place of constructor while I use method then it works why? Is there any specific reason behind it? My question is why spring designers decided not to allow @Qualifier above constructor but above method?

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;

public class Employee {
    private Company comp;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value="beanId")
    private Employee(Company comp) {
        this.comp=comp;
    }
    public Company getComp() {
        return comp;
    }
}
```

@Qualifier within argument works.. say below works it's ok

```
private Employee(@Qualifier(value="beanId") Company comp) {
        this.comp=comp;
}
```

But @Qualifier works fine above method like below why?

```
@Qualifier(value="beanId")
private void getEmpDetails(Company comp) {
        this.comp=comp;
}
```

Comment: If you have multiple parameters, which parameter should the `@Qualifier` apply to?

Comment: Ok then why below works I mean why it works for method please let me know If I am missing anything obvious Thanks :)                                                                                              @Qualifier(value="beanId")
    private void abc(Company comp) {
        this.comp=comp;
    }

Comment: Below what? What are you referring to?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I edited my question above, please have a look

Comment: I'm a bit surprised it's working on the method as according to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) that's not a valid target.

Comment: It is a valid target in the newer API. Note that your link is for version 2.5.x, and Spring is currently on version 5.0.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes for **constructors** you ***can not*** use `@Qualifier` as you use it for other methods.
`@Qualifier` annotation can be used only for the **constructor arguments**.

See [this offcial article](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) for more reference.