# How to create a wrapper for the Azure final class ServiceBusSenderClient in Spring

Tags: spring, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I need to create a wrapper for the final class [ServiceBusSenderClient](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/azure-messaging-servicebus/src/main/java/com/azure/messaging/servicebus/ServiceBusSenderClient.java)  of azure service bus

Today I instantiate the Bean in the appropriate configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class AzureServiceBusConfig {
    @Bean
    public ServiceBusSenderClient helloWorldQueueClient() {
        return new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(connectionString)
                .sender()
                .queueName(helloWorldQueueName)
                .buildClient();
    }
}
```

and then in my Service I inject it with the Qualifier (I use the same mechanism for all the clients that I need for the different queues):

```
@Service
public class AzureBusServiceImpl implements AzureBusService {
    private final ServiceBusSenderClient helloWorldQueueClient;
    public AzureBusServiceImpl(@Qualifier("helloWorldQueueClient") ServiceBusSenderClient helloWorldClient) {
        this.helloWorldQueueClient = helloWorldClient;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendHelloWorld(String message) {
        ...
    }

}
```

but I would like to create something more generic, therefore a wrapper around the ServiceBusSenderClient class so that I can customize the sendMessage(..) method and insert some custom logic. I created a custom client like this

```
@Service
public class ServiceBusSenderClientCustom {
    private final ServiceBusSenderClient serviceBusClient;
    public ServiceBusSenderClientCustom(ServiceBusSenderClient serviceBusClient) {
        this.serviceBusClient = serviceBusClient;
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        // custom logic...
        serviceBusClient.sendMessage(serviceBusMessage);
    }
}
```

but when I try to instantiate it this way it doesn't work because Spring can't inject the qualifier bean (so it doesn't find the helloWorldQueueClient bean). The problem is the same as this one
[why @Qualifier not allowed above constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42350828/why-qualifier-not-allowed-above-constructor)

```
private final ServiceBusSenderClientCustom helloWorldQueueClient;
public AzureBusServiceImpl(@Qualifier("helloWorldQueueClient") ServiceBusSenderClient helloWorldClient) {
 this.helloWorldQueueClient = new ServiceBusSenderClientCustom(helloWorldClient);
}
```

How could I make this work?

Comment: To create a wrapper for the Azure final class ServiceBusSenderClient in Spring, you can create a new class that extends ServiceBusSenderClient and add any additional functionality you need. example- `public class ServiceBusSenderClientWrapper extends ServiceBusSenderClient {
    
    public ServiceBusSenderClientWrapper(String fullyQualifiedNamespace, String queueName, ServiceBusClientBuilder builder) {
        super(fullyQualifiedNamespace, queueName, builder);
    }
    
    // add any additional functionality here`

Comment: Then, you can instantiate the wrapper class in your configuration class like this:

`@Bean
public ServiceBusSenderClientWrapper helloWorldQueueClient(ServiceBusClientBuilder builder) {
    return new ServiceBusSenderClientWrapper("your-namespace", "your-queue-name", builder);
}`  This will create a new instance of the wrapper class that you can use in your application.

Comment: References:

-   [Use Azure Service Bus in Spring applications - Use the Spring Cloud Azure Service Bus Starter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/using-service-bus-in-spring-applications#use-the-spring-cloud-azure-service-bus-starter)

Comment: The ServiceBusSenderClient is a final class, so i cant extend this one... this is my main problem

Comment: In that case you can implement a wrapper or a delegate pattern without extending the final class. This involves creating your own class that contains an instance of ServiceBusSenderClient and exposes methods to interact with it, allowing you to add custom logic. You create a class that composes a ServiceBusSenderClient rather than inherits from it. This class can define its own methods that internally call the methods of ServiceBusSenderClient, and you can inject additional logic as needed.

Comment: And then continue to configure your ServiceBusSenderClient as a Spring bean in your configuration class. Create a Spring bean for your wrapper class. This bean will consume the ServiceBusSenderClient bean. Inject ServiceBusSenderClientWrapper into your service instead of ServiceBusSenderClient directly. Hopefully This approach solves the problem of extending a final class by using composition instead of inheritance. It will allow you to encapsulate the ServiceBusSenderClient within your own class, adding custom logic around its methods while adhering to Spring's dependency injection principles

Comment: Do you have an example that works? I tried this solution but i this problem block me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42350828/why-qualifier-not-allowed-above-constructor